# "одна з дітей", "одна з людей" або "один з дітей", "один з людей"

Tags: відмінювання, число

У фразі "виявилось, що один з клієнтів був неповнолітнім" слово клієнт не вказує на стать конкретної людини, про яку йдеться, хоч саме слово клієнт є  чоловічого роду і відповідно "од**ин** з них". Слова "дитина" і "людина" жіночого роду, тож чи треба вживати жіночу форму числівника, а саме "виявилось, що одна з людей (одна з дітей) була неповнолітньою", коли неважливо або незрозуміло про яку конкретну людину (чи дитину) йдеться?

Comment: Я думаю, що _один_ у даному випадку виражає збірність (як _двоє_, _троє_...). А збірні числівники, як ми знаємо, не відмінюються за родами. Тому правильно буде лише _один_.

Comment: @Palindromer, ми не заохочуємо напів-відповіді у коментарях, це відлякує інших користувачів писати свої відповіді з тією ж аргументацією. Пропоную розгорнути ваш коментар у повноцінну відповідь, яка ґрунтується на фактичному матеріалі. Мета коментарів — покращення/уточнення дописів.

Comment: @bytebuster, я не вважаю, що мій коментар тягне на відповідь. Це лише догад без належної аргументації. Я залишив його з метою, аби, можливо, інший, більш досвідчений користувач, був підштовхнутим до до пристойної відповіді.

Answer (score 10):

Вікіпедія [каже](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%B4_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE))

> **З родом іменника** узгоджує свої родові закінчення залежний від нього **прикметник у широкому розумінні** (білий, цей, один) та
>   дієслово — у минулому часі й умовному способі.

У СУМі знаходимо

> [ДИТИ́НА](http://sum.in.ua/s/dytyna), и, **жін**. (мн. діти, ей). 1. Маленька дівчинка або
>   маленький хлопчик.
>
> [ЛЮДИ́НА](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljudyna), и, **жін**. 1. Одиничне до люди

Тому, коли з контексту незрозуміла стать, треба казати

- Одна (дитина, *ж.р.*) з дітей
- Одна (людина, *ж.р.*) з людей

А коли ж напевно відома стать, то повні версії будуть такі

- Один (хлопчик, *ч.р.*) з дітей
- Одна (дівчинка, *ж.р.*) з дітей
- Один (чоловік, *ч.р.*) з людей
- Одна (жінка, *ж.р.*) з людей

Ще [цікава цитата](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) з Вікіпедії з узгодженням родів

> У містера Сміта двоє дітей. **Хоча б одна (*ж.р.*) дитина (*ж.р.*) — хлопчик (*ч.р.*).** Яка
>   ймовірність того, що обидві дитини хлопчики?

Comment: Думка цікава, я аж +1 поставив... Але почав шукати - я не знайшов жодного прикладу використання "одна з дітей/людей", коли стать незрозуміла. Було б гарно, якби Ви знайшли приклад саме "одна з дітей", бо Ваш приклад з вікі "одна дитина" не є показовим - бракує "з". Можливо має рацію Palindomer і "один" тут має приблизно той самий сенс, що "хтось", і тому чоловічого роду...

Comment: Я не філолог, але гадаю що вважати "один з [множини]" прикметником некоректно.
Як було згадано вище, це всеж числівник. Один, коли воно у значенні єдиний - буде прикметником і мінятиме рід.